# Issue when I search for files which ends with number one

Tags: vb.net

I have a folder full of files and their names look like this...

```
FileA1.ext
FileA2.ext
FileA3.ext
FileA4.ext
FileA5.ext
FileA6.ext

FileB1.ext
FileB2.ext
FileB3.ext
FileB4.ext
FileB5.ext
FileB6.ext

FileC1.ext
FileC2.ext
FileC3.ext
FileC4.ext
FileC5.ext
FileC6.ext
```

From this folder, lets say I want to search and find every `.ext` file which ends with number 2. Using a `ListBox` and "`For Each`" into my code, I am doing this...

```
For Each FoundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(_Path, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*2.ext")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(FoundFile)
Next
```

But, If I search for every file which ends with number 1, into my `ListBox`, I also see files which ends with number 5 and 6!!! And this happens only with number 1!!! Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It‘s a known problem. This is what Microsoft says:

> Because this method checks against file names with both the 8.3 file name format and the long file name format, a search pattern similar to "*1*.txt" may return unexpected file names. For example, using a search pattern of "*1*.txt" returns "longfilename.txt" because the equivalent 8.3 file name format is "LONGFI~1.TXT".

Taken from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

---

**My suggestion**

Try to replace the asterisk (*) by a question mark (?)

```
 FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "File?1.ext")
```

**Edit**

In your case of differing suffixes in the file name you could try this:

```
FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*1?ext")
```

I‘m not sure whether this tricks the parser, but it‘s worth to give it a try, though.

Comment: The part "File" of filename is not the same in any of my file. I did like this only for the example... Any other idea? Cause If I do it like this `FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "?1.ext")` I get nothing!!!

Comment: About your edit... If I try `FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "?1ext")` I get nothing and If I try `FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "?1.ext")` I get my initial issue!!!

Comment: Sorry, but then I don‘t know how to solve it properly. The last option seems to be reading the entire file list and filtering it yourself afterwards in case of `*1.ext`. You could control this by an IF THEN ELSE so that you only have to do it yourself in this singular case.

Comment: OK I'll try something like this!!! Thank you very much for your time!!! :)

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek You could do it with something like `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(_Path, "*.ext", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).EndsWith("1")).ToArray())`. (That will need an `Imports System.IO` at the top of the code.)